# Antlr4: getting an ordered list of tokens?

Tags: java, antlr4

I have this parser rule:

```
multiplication
    : pow (operator = (TIMES | DIVIDE | FLOOR_DIVIDE | MODULO) pow)*
    ;
```

And I'm iterating over the *pow*s using `ctx.pow()`, but I would like to know too what operator there was. Unfortunately, `ctx.operator` just gives the last one encountered and `ctx.TIMES()` just gives a dumb list with a reapeted '*'.

Do I really have to do a sub-rule for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `operator +=`:

```
multiplication
    : pow (operator += (TIMES | DIVIDE | FLOOR_DIVIDE | MODULO) pow)*
    ;
```

which will cause the operators to be placed in a `List`.